# XBee shield communication

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, shields, proximity, xbee

I need to communicate between two Arduinos using XBee. I am new to XBee and hardware. The two Arduino Unos need to send a message (number) to each other and light an LED or play a sound, when they come close within a 10 meter distance.

So my doubt is which XBee shield and XBee module I need to purchase. I read about XBee series 2, XB24 etc.

Comment: Welcome to [arduino.se]! Could you add more details like what is your application? What do you intend to do? What are your requirements? What have you found? Whats confusing you? We can help only if you give us information which can enable us to do so.

Comment: Check out the XBee Buying Guide: https://www.sparkfun.com/pages/xbee_guide

Comment: Please add more details to your question, there are a lot of XBee modules and each is good a different purpose. Take a look at the link in my previous comment and learn about the different kinds of modules available and then update your question with specific details.

Comment: You lay want to give the following details to your question: the environment in which your 2 Arduinos will need to operate, the maximum distance between them, the quantity of information you need to exchange, the exchange frequency, the exchange direction (in case it might be unilateral)...

Comment: thanks guys for your reply. My question has been updated with my requirement. Please check

Comment: Your edit made your intention with the XBees a bit clearer, yes. But can you easily detect proximity using only the XBees? I don't know, but that's probably the most important part of your question.

Comment: the rssi isn't really a great test on the xbees for the purpose you're after. I hve a few around my place, the furthest is 40m away in a metal shed at the back of my yard. Because xbees are mesh, the rssi for that unit is still pretty good. You might want to look more into BLE

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of accomplishing this without some sort of proximity sensor is to measure the signal strength of the XBees.

From [page 41 of the datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-Datasheet.pdf):

> **DB (Received Signal Strength) Command**
>
> **AT Command:** ATDB
>
> **Parameter Range [read-only]:**  0x17-0x5C (XBee), 0x24-0x64 (XBee-PRO)
>
> DB parameter is used to read the received signal
>   strength (in dBm) of the last RF packet received. Reported values are
>   accurate between -40 dBm and the RF module's receiver sensitivity.
>   Absolute values are reported. For example: 0x58 = -88 dBm (decimal).
>   If no packets have been received (since last reset, power cycle or
>   sleep event), “0” will be reported.

You can use this as a **rough** estimate of the distance between two sensors. You will have to correlate signal strength to actual distance and obstructions and other factors will cause the reported value to be off.

[How to measure XBee signal strength?](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=151145.0)

This page has an example using Processing (on the computer): [XBee Signal Strength](http://www.makingthingstalk.com/chapter8/22/)

Comment: Using a single RF signal that may be on a moving object (which has its own RF absorbing and/or amplifying capability) as a proximity measurement sounds dodgy to me. Ten meters with clear line of sight, ten meters with a steel framed wall between the stations, and ten meters with a wood frame wall with electrical wires running through it will all cause unwanted variance in the measurement.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I am trying to communicate between these. Can you suggest a tutorial or something for this ? Its ruining my time.

Answer (score 2):

The "XBee" brand has two major types. Series 1 are the original ones, and are often NOT referred to by their series number. Series 2 are the newer mesh network brethren.

Most XBee's and their clones are pin compatible (there is even a Bluetooth replacement 'Bee), thus any XBee shield or adapter can be used for either series.

The difference is largely in their communication protocols. The Series 2 allow more robust mesh networking options. But for a beginner - the original (S1) provide simpler out-of-the-box networking.

There are retail packages available that include a pair of S1 XBees, an Arduino compatible breakout board, and a USB adapter to program them. This allows you to get "on the air" and setup the XBees quickly. For communication between two arduinos, a pair of shields will make physical connectivity much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ron's answer, the Series 1 is a lot easier to use, because you have to flash firmware onto Series 2s and do all kinds of setup. The S1s work out of the box.

Another thing to keep in mind is that Xbees use 3.3v I/O pins, while the Arduino uses 5v. Most Xbee shields have a Logic Level Converter to handle this, but there are some that don't, and those could damage your Xbee.